# Serilog in Asp.Net Core to SysLog sink

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, syslog, serilog

Is it possible to use Serilog to SysLog sink in Asp.Net core?

Or maybe if there is another way to sink logs to the SysLog.

Thanks.

Comment: See [Syslog.Framework.Logging](https://github.com/mguinness/syslog-framework-logging).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a working .NET Core option; the project at https://github.com/ojafri/serilog-sinks-syslog may be possible to port (it's currently built against .NET 4.x).